# end program in .java convert string to int for exiting program using letter "e"

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this grading program that I am trying a lot of things to exit the program using keyboard input, and in this case the letter "E". I created another method, but I couldn't make it to work together with the main method, and I am so new that I am just stuck. I tried using Boolean, and string to int conversion but all I get is errors. my code is below, thank you in advance, and anything helps I know that it might be a stupid question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class grading {

    public static void main (String args[]){
        boolean run = true;//this code together with bottom keep loop running
        while(run){ //the code inside this brackets will continue the loop

            int yourScore;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your Score: ");
            yourScore = input.nextInt();

            boolean kill;
            System.out.println("Press E to Exit");
            Scanner input0 = new Scanner(System.in);

            if (yourScore < 60 && yourScore >=0){
                System.out.println("You had an F, Sorry!");
            }
            else if (yourScore >=60 && yourScore < 70){
                System.out.println("You had an D, Study more!");
            }
            else if (yourScore >=70 && yourScore < 80){
                System.out.println("you had an C, you can do Better!");
            }
            else if (yourScore >= 80 && yourScore < 90){
                System.out.println("You had an B, very Well done!");
            }
            else if ( yourScore >=90 && yourScore <= 100){
                System.out.println("you had an A, you are Great!");
            }
            else if (kill = "e" != null){
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect Input!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(kill = "e" != null)` should be `(kill == "e")`. I don't know if that's your only problem, because you didn't post which errors you're getting.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It should *definitely* **not** be `kill == "e"`; That would only compare reference values. Also, `kill` ***is a*** `boolean`.

Comment: Oop, my Java is rustier than I thought. Didn't notice `kill` was boolean either. Ignore me then.

Comment: `=` is used for assignment, not comparison, `kill` is boolean and therefore can only equal `true` or `false`, and you also never assign a value to `kill` or give the user a chance to input `"e"`.

Comment: Why not `break;` or set `run = false;`?

Comment: I love how people are so shocked when code that happens to compile doesn't do anything remotely resembling what they had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your code. First of all, you are allowing user to input both number and letters but assigning the input to yourScore which is an int. If user inputs a letter then you are trying to assign that letter as an integer, which throws an InputMismatchException.

Second, you are initalizing two scanners but never using the second Scanner (i.e input0). In fact, you do not need two Scanner in this program. Only one scanner will do the job.

Third, in the last else if statement you are assigning kill = "e" != null. I am pretty sure it is not what you have intended to do. You should first be familiar with how java works. In java, the execution happens from right to left. Here the expression "e" != null will be evaluated first. Since "e" is a String it is never going to equal null. Hence, the expression "e" != null will evaluate to true. This true value is then assigned to kill variable. Hence, kill variable is always true no matter what. This is not what you want. Below is the code that works as you have intended.

```
public class grading {
public static void main (String args[]){
    boolean run = true;//this code together with bottom keep loop running
    while(run){ //the code inside this brackets will continue the loop

        int yourScore;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Score or E to exit: ");
        //checking if the input is integer or not
        if(input.hasNextInt()){ 
            yourScore = input.nextInt();

            if (yourScore < 60 && yourScore >=0){
                System.out.println("You had an F, Sorry!");
            }
            else if (yourScore >=60 && yourScore < 70){
                System.out.println("You had an D, Study more!");
            }
            else if (yourScore >=70 && yourScore < 80){
                System.out.println("you had an C, you can do Better!");
            }
            else if (yourScore >= 80 && yourScore < 90){
                System.out.println("You had an B, very Well done!");
            }
            else if ( yourScore >=90 && yourScore <= 100){
                System.out.println("you had an A, you are Great!");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect Input!");
        }
        // checking if the input is string
        else if(input.hasNext()){
            //assigning input to String varible
            String userInput = input.next();
            //comparing the input value with letter e ignoring the case
            if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                run = false;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid key. Press e to exit");
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wow man thanks for your response, I saw what I did wrong, I could have written this in a less complex way. sorry about not specifying about my running errors...the problem was mostly not accepting the letter E or e for being a String to end the program and being a rookie I thought I would get away with building two scanners and get away with it lol, but thanks everyone specially @Bijay Regmi